# Separate multiple cell values to rows

Tags: react-table

Can't seem to figure out how to separate my array into separate rows instead of appearing all in the same cell. I have a data structure like this:

```
[{Env: "DEV", Members: [John Doe, Jane Smith]}, {Env: "TEST", Members: [Joe Black, Sarah Niu]}]
```

I have Env displaying on the main table, with the Members displaying as sub components. However, the members display all in the same cell. Is there a way to get them to display in separate rows, or would I need to list them out? e.g. [{Env: DEV, Member: John Doe, Env: DEV, Member: Jane Smith}] Current code below:

```
return (
    <div>
      <ReactTable
         data={this.props.data}
         columns={envColumn}
         className="-striped -highlight"
         defaultPageSize={10}
         SubComponent={row => 
           return (
              <ReactTable
                data={[row.original]}
                columns={memberColumn}
                defaultPageSize={3}
                showPagination={false}
               />
            )
         }}
       />
     </div>
 )
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by using function for data:

```
separateMembers(members) {
        var array = []
        members.forEach((item) => {
            array.push({ Member: item })
        })
        return array;
}
```